# How to force libGDX to set display mode?

Tags: libgdx

The following code represents my attempt to switch display modes. I've had to include the redundant `setWindowedMode` because without it, libGDX would not force the change required to reflect the changes made by `System.setProperty...` and the border would not disappear/reappear from the window.

```
public static void setGraphicsMode() {
    switch (getString(OptionConstant.DISPLAY_MODE)) {
        case "windowed borderless":
            System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Window.undecorated", "true");
            break;
        case "windowed":
            System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Window.undecorated", "false");
            break;  
        default:
            break;
    }

    Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(getInt(OptionConstant.RESOLUTION_X) + 1, 
                                 getInt(OptionConstant.RESOLUTION_Y));

    Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(getInt(OptionConstant.RESOLUTION_X), 
                                 getInt(OptionConstant.RESOLUTION_Y));

    switch (getString(OptionConstant.DISPLAY_MODE)) {
        case "fullscreen":
            Graphics.DisplayMode displayMode = Gdx.graphics.getDisplayMode();
            Gdx.graphics.setFullscreenMode(displayMode);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this without the the redundant call?